# Local storage on Hybrid Application

Tags: cordova, local-storage, phonegap

I want to develop an offline application. I want to keep it in the local file. first option is local file to read and write. then secone one is localstorage feature. if i use localstorage,  is this situation a problem?

After the user has registered the data, if user cleans browser data on devices, is empty and clean localstorage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the type of data you want to store locally you would pick one or the other.

Be warned that **localStorage** has strong size limitations, according to [this site](https://www.sitepoint.com/html5-local-storage-revisited/) you can only store up to 2 MB on Android 4.x and 5MB on iOS, this is barely enough to hold user account session data and nothing else.

So it depends on the type and amount of data you want to cache, if you think 2 MB won't be enough, you can forget about localStorage and use the filesystem.

And yes, when the user manually clears the app's data it will definitely clean all the localStorage data as well.

Comment: Ok thanks. What do you think WebSql or SqlLite about that?